# Какой командой можно запустить обычное приложение, как службу Windows?

Tags: c#, cmd

Как создать, зарегистрировать новую службу Windows из обычного приложения и поставить его в автозагрузку?
У этого приложения будут права администратора?

Comment: Уточните вопрос, вам нужно запустить приложение как службу, или службу из вашего приложения?

Answer (score 2):

Есть программа обертка для таких целей: https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw
По сути она просто запустит приложение с нужными параметрами. При остановке службы опять же запустит его, с другими параметрами. Права у приложения будут LOCAL_SYSTEM, но это можно изменить в свойствах службы.

Comment: Что-то она какая-то слишком сложная для этой задачи

Answer (score 1):

Можно через консоль, т.е создаешь внутри программы процесс консоли и посылаешь ему что-то типа этого:

```
 Sc create MyService binPath=C:\MyService\MyService.exe DisplayName=″My  New Service″ type=own start=auto
```

Служба так же автоматом добавится в автозапуск.

Подробнее [тут](http://windowsnotes.ru/cmd/sozdanie-sluzhby-v-windows/)

Еще есть Installutil, но если не ошибаюсь, то у него меньше возможностей чем у SC...

Comment: Эм.. Ну не заработает же? Вроде нельзя взять произвольное приложение и скормить в `sc`. И почему в коде кавычки наклоные?

Comment: А разве в вопросе идет речь про произвольное приложение? Я тело вопроса понял так : Есть приложение и оно должно зарегистрировать другую службу. Как-то двусмысленно трактовать можно...

Comment: Хм.. Тогда ok. просто я понял вопрос так: "есть произвольное приложение и я хочу его запустить как службу" :)

Comment: О, нашёл! Там же написано: _"из обычного приложения"_.

Comment: С этой темой есть грязный лайфхак, когда в кач-ве binpath передается, что то вроде "CMD.exe /c /b path_to_exe". Тогда запускается консоль и прежде чем быть грохнутой (ибо не служба) вызовет в безграфическом режиме нужное приложение. К слову работает не у всех, у меня так и не получилось, но множество отзывов положительных слышал о такой методике.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая программка - *XyNtService* [с исходниками](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=719&av=49654).

Я ее допиливал. [Здесь](https://dmitrybond.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/fixed-n-adjusted-xyntservice/) исправленная и улучшенная версия (с исходниками).

На *OneDrive* - там два файла: `XYNTServiceProject_src.zip` и `XYNTServiceProject_v03.zip`

Answer (score 1):

Произвольное приложение запустить как службу Windows нельзя, оно должно соответствовать требованиям службы.

Можно сделать простую службу, которая будет запускать и контролировать произвольное приложение, указанное в параметрах например. Чтобы не сильно страдать при создании службы, можно воспользоваться, например, TopShelf, который доступен из NuGet, и свести работу к минимуму.

Права которые будут у службы настраиваются, и могут быть любыми от системных до пользовательских. При необходимости, права могут быть изменены без переустановки службы, но с обязательным перезапуском.